# Create a function with two parameters and list numbers between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I need to list all numbers between user input's. Actually I need to list only the odd numbers but I can do that if I can list all numbers.

Here's what I have done so far

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[ofdnumbers] 
(
    @MaxValue as int,
    @MinValue as int
) 
Returns @table table( Sonuclar int not null)
as
Begin          
    Declare @Num as int
    set @Num=@MinValue
    set @Num=@Num+1

    insert into @table
        select sonuclar from @table
     
    return @table
end
```

Comment: Look up 'while', as in `while @num <= @MinValue begin ... end`, and get rid of the select

Comment: @JasonGoemaat a while loop is absolutely the worst way possible for this. This needs to be set based, not iterative.

Comment: You have created what is known as a multi-statement table valued function and the performance is dreadful. This should be done as an inline table valued function which means a single select statement. You can do that easily for this problem using a tally or numbers table.

Comment: Here is one of the best articles on tally tables. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1

Comment: Look at the 6 number series generator posts here: https://sqlperformance.com/author/itzikbengan/page/2

Comment: Okay thank you. I will also try to use tally tables to create the function. tally tables looks usefull.

Answer (score 2):

One *possible* function you could implement would be something along the lines of the following.

As illustrated by the various linked articles there are numerous ways to create a number series, the best approach is probably to have a permanent numbers/tally table with enough rows to cater for all requirements that you can just directly select from.

The following (or something similar) will provide the best relative performance:

```
create or alter function dbo.OddNumbers(@MaxValue int, @MinValue int)
returns table
as
return 
select Sonuclar from (
  select top (@MaxValue - @MinValue + 1) 
    Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) + @MinValue - 1 as Sonuclar
  from master.dbo.spt_values
)n
where Sonuclar % 2 = 1;
```

Comment: as far as i understand after return;
second line selects rows between values,
third line identifies row numbers that are over min value as sonuclar,
and last line returns row numbers where row numbers are odd.

am i right ? 
i am going to mess with it more to understand. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sounds a resonable explanation. Just `select * from dbo.OddNumbers(100,50)` as an example.